# How do I check if a certain array already contains the imdbID and prevent it from adding it again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

[image]

Each movie is only supposed to be added to the favourites list once but this bug makes it so that every time I change the page and go back to that certain movie page and I add it, it pushes itself into the favourites array. How do I check if a certain imdbID is already there and prevent the app from adding it into the state?

```
 updateFavorites = movie => {

    if (!this.state.favorites.includes(movie)) {

        const newFavoriteList = this.state.favorites;
        newFavoriteList.push(movie);
        this.setState(state => ({
            favorites: newFavoriteList
        }));


        console.log("Added to your favorites.");

    } else {
        const newFavoriteList = this.state.favorites;
        newFavoriteList.splice(newFavoriteList.indexOf(movie), 1);
        this.setState(state => ({
            favorites: newFavoriteList
        }));
        console.log("Removed from your favorites.");
    }

};
```

This is how I add and remove my movies from the favourites list.

Comment: how are you managing state? My best guess is you need to hook into the React lifestyles (`componentEillReceiveProps`, etc)

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes` uses the sameValueZero method to determine equality, that is, it does a comparison of if the objects are the same objects in memory (in this case). Instead of using includes, I would use `Array.prototype.find` or `findIndex` and then check the imdbID and compare those.

Comment: This should be an answer @lemieuxster.

Answer (score 0):

As told in the comments you can use `.find` or `.findIndex` for this comparison. Also, you can use `.filter` instead of `.splice` and `.indexOf` to remove a movie. Personally I prefer this method.

```
updateFavorites = ( movie ) => {
    const { favorites } = this.state;
    const checkMovie = favorites.find( fav => fav.imdbID === movie.imdbID );

    if (!checkMovie) {
      return this.setState(
          prevState => ( { favorites: [ ...prevState.favorites, movie ] } ) );
    }

    const newFavoriteList = favorites.filter( fav => fav.imdbID !== movie.imdbID );
    this.setState( { favorites: newFavoriteList } );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It worked for me

```
let checkArray = favorites.every( (item) => {
 return item.imdbID !== newItem.imdbID; // newItem is new element for insert
})

if(checkArray) {
  //code for insert newItem
}
```